# how to insert data into pages in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js

I have recently begun to work with NodeJS, after a long time working with PHP, and i'm wondering if there was anything similar to 'echo'. a way of sending the data as parts, allowing me to send my own values in between. For example, writing the structure for a section of a website in html, then using node to send the relevant data inside of the div.

Comment: My suggestion, look into React.JS, Angular.JS or Vue.JS for frontend application.

Comment: There is no equivalent. Generally Nodejs works only on server-side and you need some software to expose an API or similar. As mentioned, you wanna checkout packages like "flask" or  express  for the API construction(which is pretty easy) and you have to use fetch, websockets OR xhttprequest for getting the data from the server. 

What you may find interesting is serverside rendering, checkout https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache

Or a framework like react, vue or angular.

Comment: @SilvanBregy — "Generally Nodejs works only on server-side" Umm. Yes. Like PHP. Which the question is asking how to be more like. Node.js is quite capable of generating HTML instead of a web service. The Express guide even covers template engines.

Comment: @Quentin , 
You are right. I tried to explain the differences but let's refer to the answer instead to my bad english.. '' ^^
Pfff, 22k answers. GG ! '' ,
Wait, let me count mine... Ahh, I have like, not even twenty ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "yes". You can repeatedly [`write`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback) to the `response` object and then call [`end`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback) on it when you are done.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
response.write("foo"); 
response.write("bar"); 
response.write("baz"); 
response.end();
```

**However, that generally isn't the approach taken for good reason.**

[Separating your concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) (e.g. splitting "data fetching" and "HTML generation") usually makes things more manageable.

This is why the most common way to build pages server-side with Node.js is to collect all the data for the page into an object and then pass it into a [template](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

You can, of course, split the data collection logic up into functions in their own modules so you can end up with something like:

```
const my_data = {
    header: get_header_data(request),
    content: get_template_name_data(request),
};
response.render('template_name', my_data)
```

With as much division into smaller chunks are you like.